# What should be used in place of defaultHTTPHeaders in Alamofire 5?

Tags: swift

The code mentioned below is not working for Alamofire 5.

`configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders`

I have tried replacing it with `HTTPHeaders.default` as shown below:

`configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = HTTPHeaders.default`

but still, it did not work.

Comment: what error are you getting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Try setting it as

configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = HTTPHeaders.default.dictionary